# Jquery disable cache buster for external scripts downloaded after calling the jquery load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, caching

When loading html content through $.load, and the html content contains `<script>` tags referencing javascript files, the linked Javascript files are appended with a cache busting parameter, which prevents the file from being cached by the browser.

So, instead of requesting some­thing like `<script src="/js/foo.js">`, it requests `<script src="/js/foo.js?_=123123">`, caus­ing the script to be loaded every time.

Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to force caching

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/yourpage",
    cache: true,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
        $("#content").html(data);
    }
});
```

.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
cache: true // Enable cache as jQuery won't let the script be cached by default
});
```

Comment: ajaxSetup is global so I didn't want to use that. I might try your first suggestion though.